# How to create recursive function for hierarchy results from PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following records in "test_group" table, I got the array results from SELECT query.

```
group_id    group_name      parent_id
1           fruits          0
2           vegetables      0
3           one seed        1
4           many seed       1
5           seedless        2
6           many seed       2
7           mango           3
8           guava           4
9           jack fruit      4
10          gooseberry      3
11          drumstick       6
12          beans           6
13          onion           5
14          cauli flower    5
```

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT * FROM test_groups;
```

**Results:**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 1
            [group_name] => fruits
            [parent_id] => 0
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 2
            [group_name] => vegetables
            [parent_id] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 3
            [group_name] => one seed
            [parent_id] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 4
            [group_name] => many seed
            [parent_id] => 1
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 5
            [group_name] => seedless
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 6
            [group_name] => many seed
            [parent_id] => 2
        )
    [6] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 7
            [group_name] => mango
            [parent_id] => 3
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 8
            [group_name] => guava
            [parent_id] => 4
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 9
            [group_name] => jack fruit
            [parent_id] => 4
        )
    [9] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 10
            [group_name] => gooseberry
            [parent_id] => 3
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 11
            [group_name] => drumstick
            [parent_id] => 6
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 12
            [group_name] => beans
            [parent_id] => 6
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 13
            [group_name] => onion
            [parent_id] => 5
        )
    [13] => Array
        (
            [group_id] => 14
            [group_name] => cauli flower
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

)
```

I want the following output from these results. How to frame the hierarchy levels with these results set? Please help me and thanks for advance.

```html
<ul>
<li>Fruits</li>
    <ul>
        <li>one seed</li>
        <ul>
            <li>mango</li>
            <li>gooseberry</li>
        </ul>
        <li>many seed</li>
        <ul>
            <li>guava</li>
            <li>jack fruit</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
<li>Vegetables</li>
    <ul>
        <li>seedless</li>
        <ul>
            <li>onion</li>
            <li>cauli flower</li>
        </ul>
        <li>many seed</li>
        <ul>
            <li>drumstick</li>
            <li>beans</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive functions, so it is not well suited to this (adjacency-list) model of storing hierarchical data.  If possible, you should consider adopting a more SQL-friendly model (such as nested sets or a transitive closure).

Comment: I want the results from recursive function without sub query, Is it possible in PHP array?

Comment: perhaps if you create your array in a different way? two dimensional... one for parent_id and for each parent, an inner array holding the children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build list using recursion or without:

Using Recursion:

```
function array_to_tree_recursive(array $array, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if ($v['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            $return[$k] = $v; 
            $return[$k]['children'] = array_to_tree_recursive($array, $v['group_id']);  
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Without Recursion:

```
function array_to_tree(array $array, $parent_id = 0)
{
    $array = array_combine(array_column($array, 'group_id'), array_values($array));

    foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
        if (isset($array[$v['parent_id']])) {
            $array[$v['parent_id']]['children'][$k] = &$v;
        }
        unset($v);
    }

    return array_filter($array, function($v) use ($parent_id) {
        return $v['parent_id'] == $parent_id;
    });
}
```

Convert tree to list:

```
function tree_to_list(array $tree) {
    $return = "";

    foreach ($tree as $branch) {
        $return .= "\n<li>".$branch['group_name']."</li>";
        if (isset($branch['children']) && sizeof($branch['children'])) {
            $return .= tree_to_list($branch['children']);
        }
    }

    return "\n<ul>{$return}</ul>\n";
}
```

Usage:

```
echo tree_to_list(array_to_tree($a));
```

Output:

```
<ul>
<li>fruits</li>
<ul>
<li>one seed</li>
<ul>
<li>mango</li>
<li>gooseberry</li></ul>

<li>many seed</li>
<ul>
<li>guava</li>
<li>jack fruit</li></ul>
</ul>

<li>vegetables</li>
<ul>
<li>seedless</li>
<ul>
<li>onion</li>
<li>cauli flower</li></ul>

<li>many seed</li>
<ul>
<li>drumstick</li>
<li>beans</li></ul>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you b.b3rn4rd, I got it. your code is very optimized and simple.

Comment: shouldnt the 8th line in the first code block be named "**array_to_tree_recursive**" instead of "array_to_tree" ?

Comment: The non-recursive one doesn't seem to work if you add another layer of depth, which I needed for my situation, but the recursive one worked just fine, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First we create some basic tree management functions:

```
/* in a separate file for your custom functions: */
function createTreeFromList($list) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach($list AS $item) {
        if(isset($tree[$item['group_id']])) {
            array_merge($tree[$item['group_id']], $item);
        }
        else {
            $tree[$item['group_id']] = $item;
        }
        if(!isset($tree[$item['parent_id']]) {
            $tree[$item['parent_id']] = array();
            $tree[$item['parent_id']]['children'] = array();
        }
        $tree[$item['parent_id']]['children'] []= &$item;
    }
    return($tree);
}

function printTree($tree) {
    echo("<ul>");
    foreach($tree AS $node) {
        echo("<li>".$node['group_name']."</li>");
        if(!empty($node['children'])) {
            echo("<li>");
            printTree($node['children']);
            echo("</li>");
        }
    }
    echo("</ul>");
}
```

The we use them:

```
/* in our current file */

/* gain access to the functions we've defined */
include('path/to/our/functions_file.php');

/* select all rows in the tree: */
$sql = "SELECT * ...";
$rows = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();

/* iterate over the list in order to create an equivalent tree: */
$tree = createTreeFromList($rows);

/* Then we print the tree: */
printTree($tree);
```

Comment: Please test & tweak the code yourself, I just wrote it off the top of my head and didn't test it.

Comment: Hi Mihai, I tried, but it won't work. Can you explain how to frame it?

Comment: @RameshMoorthy Follow this: http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/08/php-adjacency-list-hierarchy-tree-traversal.html

Comment: What do you mean by "frame"?

Comment: Hi Mihai, How to create it? If possible, Can you explain the step by step? Because I tried but it won't work for me.

Comment: I've update some very basic usage instructions. Unfortunately I suspect you need to go through a web development tutorial or two to have a better understanding of what the code does and what each piece of it represents. Otherwise you'll have a hard time asking well formed questions and working and we'll have a hard time knowing what to assume about skill level.

Comment: I didn't get the proper array result set from your updated code.

Comment: My bad, I used `print`, I should have written `printTree`. It's updated now.

Comment: +1, nice method, the only problem is that it does not remove child notes after they have been appointed... if that makes sence. I made solved this using one array.

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd You're right, I didn't test my code, so I didn't notice it leaves the second/third level children on the first level list as well. But OP should get the point and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = query;
for($i=0 to end)
    find_child($i); 


function find_child($gid){
    echo "<ul>";
    for($i=0 to end){
        if($result[$i].parent_id == gid){
            echo "<li>"+$result+"</li>"
            find_child($result[i].group_id);
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: This will iterate over the result list many many times. I think the complexity is `O(N!)` or `O(N!-N)`. In any case very inefficient. And in case you need to do this in several places in your page you'll have to compute it every time.

Comment: In my answer I only have to iterate through the list once to create a hierarchical tree based on the initial list (which is `O(N)`). After that you can walk the tree to print it in the desired format (another `O(N)`). So let's say a total of `O(2N)` for creating & printing a tree.